# Switchback from Xubuntu to macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My friend recently acquired a corner store and in the office, the previous (disappeared) tenants left a 2012 MacBook Pro 15.4". We found a proper charger and turned it on: it has Xubuntu on it.

How can we switch it back to macOS?

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac (one which actually is running macOS)?

Comment: Is there a reason the OP could not use internet recovery? Also, there could be a dual boot arrangement. In other words, macOS might already be on the Mac.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your help ! I have a mid-2009 iMac running High Sierra i could use in the process if it Can help.   Regarding internet, i did not succeed to connect on my home wifi with the Xubuntued macbookpro.

Comment: Just tried INTERNET RECOVERY using the keys combo + my wifi. went good until the CHOOSE THE DISC to install the OS. There is no disc option to choose from. I went to check the disks and it seems they are OK according to the verify/repair program.

Comment: GREAT ! Thank you for your help. I had to partition and use a boot on USB... but in the end, the macbook is now on High Sierra ! Case closed ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Latest supported macOS version for this Mac is 10.15.7 (Catalina).

You can follow [this Apple webpage](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). You will need another Mac running macOS.

Summary : download installer, create a bootable USB key through terminal, then boot under the key to format disk then install macOS.

Note : if the EFI (bios) has been changed, it is possible that starting up with alt key do not allow you to choose startup disk. In this case, you will have to find how to choose boot disk with this EFI.